# Difference between haemocoel and coelom

Tags: zoology, embryology, invertebrates, arthropod

I am looking for an **embryological perspective** on the following question.

I know about coelom derivation, but I want to know how haemocoel is derived and how it is fundamentally different from coelom.

True coelom is formed by the cavity formed in mesoderm. It is lined by mesothelium on both sides, whereas on the other side pseudo coelom is cavity which is lined by endothelium and mesothelium. However, the formation of haemocoel is not clear to me.

I have looked for in many books, but I have not been able to find an embryological perspective and what happens to coelom in which haemocoel is present.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for the same thing and i found the answer in the anatomy of molluscs[image]

you can clearly see that coelom is different from haemocoel and coelom is greatly reduced.
Haemocoel is a pseudocoelom it is a body cavity but not lined with mesoderm at all sides

Comment: Ca you add the source (website) of the image and add references to your answer?